# How connect external database with docker container using wildfly 15

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-container, wildfly-15

I'm new in Docker, I try to deploy a web application with Docker using WildFly 15 images that. My app uses a local database (MySQL). Once I tried to run my container I always get this log exception:

```
> Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/my_DataSource
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:690)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.tx.TxConnectionManagerImpl.getManagedConnection(TxConnectionManagerImpl.java:440)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.allocateConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:789)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource.getConnection(WrapperDataSource.java:138)
        ... 127 more
Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:531)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:438)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:1326)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.getConnection(SemaphoreConcurrentLinkedDequeManagedConnectionPool.java:499)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getTransactionNewConnection(AbstractPool.java:714)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.AbstractPool.getConnection(AbstractPool.java:613)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.AbstractConnectionManager.getManagedConnection(AbstractConnectionManager.java:624)
        ... 130 more
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
> 
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1121)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:357)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2519)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2304)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:834)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:416)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:346)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:443)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:141)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource.getConnection(MysqlDataSource.java:111)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource.getXAConnection(MysqlXADataSource.java:50)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:516)
        ... 136 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:452)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:262)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:307)
        ... 153 more
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/my_DataSource
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ000453: Unable to get managed connection for java:/my_DataSource
    Caused by: javax.resource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
    Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
> 
> The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)"}}
```

I tried to run my container using those lines but I still have the same problem:

```
docker run -p8085:8080 --add-host=my_db:my_idAdr img_Id
docker run -p8085:8080 --add-host=my_db:127.0.0.1 img_Id
docker run -p8084:8080 -d --network=host -e DB_PORT=3306 -e DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 img_id
```

Also, when I ping my host IP address from the Docker container it works successfully.

Comment: Show your `my_DataSource` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You use `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1`  and refer to the container network, not the **host** one (where your DB is run).
One of the options to reach your **host** DB is using the interface IP address.

To show your interfaces and addresses:

On Windows:

```
ipconfig /all
```

On Mac or some Linux-based distributives

```
ifconfig
```

Comment: @Aya CHAHBENI Describe exact steps you did and your network configuration in the question part